# Setting SessionScoped ManagedBean using Servlet API

Tags: session, jsf-2, servlet-filters, managed-bean

I have a filter configured in my application that intercepts all the requests and it needs to set the value for a certain bean `UserInfoBean` named as `userInfo` which is defined as a `ManagedBean` and that is `SessionScoped`.

When I attempt to create an instance of `UserInfoBean` and set it into a session with name `userInfo` and attempt to access it on a JSF page like `#{userInfo.firstName}`, a `null` value is returned. What is wrong in my approach?

The bean class is:

```
@ManagedBean (name="userInfo")
@SessionScoped
public class UserInfoBean {
    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public UserInfoBean(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

The filter code is:

```
public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ....
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("userInfo", new UserInfoBean("Joe"));
    ....
}
```

The JSF Code is:

```
<h:outputText value="#{userInfo.firstName}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
@ManagedBean (name="userInfo")
@SessionScoped
```

from the class. You're managing the bean yourself by a servlet filter instead of by JSF.

The `session.setAttribute("userInfo", new UserInfoBean("Joe"));` will already make it available by `#{userInfo}`. JSF doesn't need to create/override it.

Note that `@ManagedProperty("#{userInfo}")` will still keep working; it doesn't require the target object to be a JSF managed bean, but just that it's available by the specified EL expression "the usual way".

Answer (score 0):

You can access your bean with

```
UserInfoBean userInfo = (UserInfoBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("userInfoBean");
```

But bean has to be already created in the session before that. So if Filter should do some authentication, then check if the bean is null or username is wrong, then you know you've got unathorized user.